# Shell script for replacing :*; with a comma

Tags: css, bash, sed, css-variables

I have some css color variables that look this:

```
--state-success-text:        #3c763d;
--state-success-background:  #dff0d8;
```

I want to replace the hex color code with a comma.  So in other words I want a comma separated list of just the color variables that looks like this:

```
state-success-text, state-success-background, ...
```

Thoughts on how to code a bash script that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there,

```
sed 's/--\(.*\):.*;/\1, /'
```

Should do it. When you do `:*;`, the column will be expanded several time, adding a `.` will mean any character.

EDIT: Modified to also remove the `--`.

Comment: I updated the question a bit - I'd also like to remove the two `--` at the beginning of each variable.

Comment: Oops I think I may have removed someone's comment accidentally - sorry about that.

Comment: Modified to remove the leading double slash, and group the variable name before printing. I think the comment mentioned the end of line? Do you want to remove it too?

Answer (score 3):

here is another approach, this won't have a comma after the last entry

```
cut -d: -f1 file | paste -sd,
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward `awk(1)` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"; ORS=", "}; { print $1 }' input
```